# Reaction Embed that update with the users

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I am trying to create a 1v1 system so that users are able react to the message (Embed) that the bot sends then it will add them to a list I can only seem to get that to work in the description and not anywhere else.  I mean I did change the embed.description = response; to lets say embec.footer = response; and that didn't seem to work but I am not worries about that.

**Issue with the remove reaction**

So with the remove when a user removes a reaction this will remove all of them, is there a to make is so it will remove just the one user and leave the other users there?

```js
Client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();

  if (user.bot) return;
  if(!reaction.message.guild) return;
  
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `${u.username}, Reacted with ${reaction.emoji}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `${u.username}, Reacted with ${reaction.emoji}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `${u.username}, Reacted with ${reaction.emoji}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `${u.username}, Reacted with ${reaction.emoji}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `${u.username}, Reacted with ${reaction.emoji}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
});

**Issue with the add reactions**

So when a user adds a different reaction to the bot it will not add their name to the embed it will only add it if the user has the same reaction if the reaction is different then it will not add it. 

Client.on("messageReactionRemove", async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();

  if (user.bot) return;
  if(!reaction.message.guild) return;
  
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `React to this message to join the battle.`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += ``;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `React to this message to join the battle.`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `React to this message to join the battle.`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `React to this message to join the battle.`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
});
```

**Update**

So I have now worked out how to get it so the add reaction will stack all the members instead of for (var u of users.map(user => user)) I used (var u of users.map(users => users)) this seems to have fixed the add reaction issue.

However it will only do it if the users have the same reaction it will not do it with separate reactions.